# Restricting direct access to Azure sql external data source

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake-gen2, row-level-security

I try to created Row-Level-Security in a Azure Synapse ondemand database. The data is stored in Azure Datalake Storage Gen 2. The script is working fine, but members of the restricted user group can still run the OPENROWSET command manually and see al the data. Does somebody knows what part I'am missing?

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL WorkspaceIdentity
WITH IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity'
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [DataLakeStorage] WITH (LOCATION = N'https://theorders.dfs.core.windows.net/', CREDENTIAL =  WorkspaceIdentity )
GO

GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL::[WorkspaceIdentity] TO [MyTestGroup];
GO

CREATE VIEW [model].[my_orders] as
    SELECT * FROM
    OPENROWSET(BULK 'dimorders/*.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'DataLakeStorage', FORMAT = 'parquet') as rows
    WHERE [UserName] = suser_name()
GO

GRANT SELECT ON [model].[my_orders] TO [MyTestGroup]
GO
```

The example script for receiving all the data, without restriction

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(BULK 'dimorders/*.parquet',
DATA_SOURCE = 'DataLakeStorage', FORMAT = 'parquet') as rows
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow below steps which shows how to give a user permission to access a particular database.

> Note - The steps below need to be run for each SQL pool to grant user
> access to all SQL databases except in section Workspace-scoped
> permission where you can assign a user a sysadmin role at the
> workspace level.

1. Set up security groups
2. Prepare your ADLS Gen2 storage account
3. Create and configure your Azure Synapse Workspace
4. Grant the workspace MSI access to the default storage container
5. Grant Synapse administrators the Azure Contributor role on the workspace
6. Assign SQL Active Directory Admin role
7. Grant access to SQL pools
8. Add users to security groups
9. Network security

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control#supporting-more-advanced-scenarios